# How i can see the products (or items) from a SaleItemLineDetail from Quick Books?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I've been looking for a way to watch for the product that have a sales tax from a sale receipt or a invoice  in QuickBooks.
I found the property of Salestaxitems, but how i can implement in C# after connecting my app to my company sandbox.
sorry if the question was not very clear and thanks for reading.

Comment: Thanks for awnser, i see more details form the salestaxeitems. The items  that i need for take are the type of sales and the % of them and i found it.
tax for travel 9% for example.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link for creating Invoice with sales tax in C#-
https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6500373

I believe you are getting confused with various line details.
Please read this docs for more information n each linedetail type-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting ->Complex Types

Important points to note is that Invoice will have 2 different line for tax and for items.
For Taxes, you need to refer TxnTaxDetail line.
For items, you need to refer SalesItemLineDetail line.

Now SalesItemLinDetail will have a taxCodeRef value of TAX for US companies. When you do a read for an Invoice, loop through the SalesItemLineDetail tag and see if taxCodeRef= TAX is set, then read the corresponding ItemRef value.

The following code can be used to read SalesItemLineDetail-

```
QueryService<Invoice> bill1QueryService = new QueryService<Invoice>(context);
Invoice bill11 = bill1QueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("select * from Invoice").FirstOrDefault<Invoice>();


 SalesItemLineDetail a1 = (SalesItemLineDetail)bill11.Line[0].AnyIntuitObject;

                        if(a1.TaxCodeRef.Value=="TAX")
                        {
                            string taxCodeid = a1.ItemRef.Value;
                            object unitprice = a1.AnyIntuitObject;
                            decimal quantity = a1.Qty;
                        }
```

Comment: Excellent. you have to explicit cast it with (SalesItemLineDetail)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SalesTax from QBO UI and refer that from an invoice. That way(from the response XML/JSON) you'll get the object structure.

I guess, you are using the official .net devkit(it has all the related properties to construct POCO)
http://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/IPPDotNetDevKitV3/
https://developer.intuit.com/docs?redirectid=acctgNET

Here is a sample:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2015-02-02T20:36:29.188-08:00">
  <QueryResponse startPosition="1" maxResults="1" totalCount="1">
    <Invoice domain="QBO" sparse="false">
      <Id>1</Id>
      <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
      <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2015-02-02T20:34:40-08:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2015-02-02T20:36:21-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>
      </MetaData>
      <DocNumber>1001</DocNumber>
      <TxnDate>2015-02-02</TxnDate>
      <CurrencyRef name="United States Dollar">USD</CurrencyRef>
      <Line>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <LineNum>1</LineNum>
        <Description>random dex</Description>
        <Amount>20.00</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
        <SalesItemLineDetail>
          <ItemRef name="Services">12</ItemRef>
          <UnitPrice>20</UnitPrice>
          <Qty>1</Qty>
          <TaxCodeRef>TAX</TaxCodeRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
      </Line>
      <Line>
        <Amount>20.00</Amount>
        <DetailType>SubTotalLineDetail</DetailType>
        <SubTotalLineDetail />
      </Line>
      <TxnTaxDetail>
        <TxnTaxCodeRef>2</TxnTaxCodeRef>
        <TotalTax>2.25</TotalTax>
        <TaxLine>
          <Amount>2.25</Amount>
          <DetailType>TaxLineDetail</DetailType>
          <TaxLineDetail>
            <TaxRateRef>1</TaxRateRef>
            <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
            <TaxPercent>11.25</TaxPercent>
            <NetAmountTaxable>20.00</NetAmountTaxable>
          </TaxLineDetail>
        </TaxLine>
      </TxnTaxDetail>
      <CustomerRef name="John Doe">1</CustomerRef>
      <SalesTermRef>3</SalesTermRef>
      <DueDate>2015-03-04</DueDate>
      <TotalAmt>22.25</TotalAmt>
      <ApplyTaxAfterDiscount>false</ApplyTaxAfterDiscount>
      <PrintStatus>NotSet</PrintStatus>
      <EmailStatus>NotSet</EmailStatus>
      <Balance>22.25</Balance>
      <Deposit>0</Deposit>
      <AllowIPNPayment>false</AllowIPNPayment>
      <AllowOnlinePayment>false</AllowOnlinePayment>
      <AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>false</AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>
      <AllowOnlineACHPayment>false</AllowOnlineACHPayment>
    </Invoice>
  </QueryResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```